# One click Google Photos backup & sync turn on/off

Tags: settings, sync, tasker, xposed-framework, google-photos

Google photos has this option nested within it settings → backup & sync.

I use [Xposed Edge](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jozein.xedge&hl=en_US) for various gesture based activities in which you can configure an apps activity as gesture. But I am unable to find this particular activity. Is there any other way (Using any xposed module or any other way) I can configure a toggle (QS Tile will be much better) which enables or disables Google Photos sync option?

Comment: Welcome to our site. +1 for an interesting question. AFAIK, there isn't a way - that activity is not exposed outside the app . Hope you get a solution

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been searching for this for a long time. If I get any other solution for this I will update here.

Comment: That's a good idea :) Meanwhile,please continue to contribute to this site